# Variable casting in Tornado

Tags: python, variables, casting, tornado

I have those variables:

```
PERM_READ = 0x01
PERM_WRITE = 0x02
PERM_CMDS = 0x04
```

and a function that check the permission on a network or on a sensor. A function that determines what is the permission of the user.

This is the function:

```
def check_network_access(self, network, access=None, raise_err=True):
    if access is None:
        access = PERM_READ
    else:
        assert(access > 0)
        assert(access <= (PERM_READ + PERM_WRITE + PERM_CMDS))
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']
    # Does the network exist?
    net = self.get_network(network)
    if not net:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404, "not found")

    self.lock_tables('read', ['nets_permissions'])
    perms = self.db.get("SELECT * FROM nets_permissions WHERE network_id=%s AND \
                        user_id=%s", network, usr_id)
    self.unlock_tables()
    if (not perms) or ((perms['perm'] & access) != access):
        if (raise_err):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403, "access forbidden")
        else: 
            return False
    return True
```

Now for example i have an error when I call a page with this handler:

```
class NetworkStatusHandler(BaseHandler):
# Requires authentication 
@tornado.web.authenticated
def get(self, nid):

    # Retrieve the current user 
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']

    perm = self.db.query("SELECT n.perm FROM nets_permissions as n \
                          WHERE n.network_id=%s AND n.user_id=%s", nid, int(usr_id))

    # Check whether the user has access to the network 
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, perm)
    net = self.get_network(nid)
    # Render the networks page
    self.render("networkstatus.html", net=net)
```

The error I have is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 988, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1739, in wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "./wsn.py", line 663, in get
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, perm)
  File "./wsn.py", line 250, in check_network_access
    assert(access <= (PERM_READ + PERM_WRITE + PERM_CMDS))
AssertionError
```

I think this is a problem in the casting of the variable perm, when it's passed to the check_network_access function...

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What's the value and type of "access" on line 250 in check_network_access?

Comment: 4. The query put 4 in perm in the handler. So when the function is called perm, and so access, is 4. But my variable PERM_CMDS is 0x04. So I don't know if there's a problem...

Comment: The reason I asked about the type is because if it's the string "4" then it will fail the assertion. You could try "casting" perm to int in the handler by doing self.check_network_access(nid, int(perm)).

Comment: I've tried... but the error I have is  File "./wsn.py", line 663, in get
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, int(perm))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

In the DB the column perm in nets_permissions is already an int value.

Comment: What library are you using for DB access? MySQLdb? The built-in tornado helpers? SQLite3? Other?

Comment: MySQL. But i think fot Tornado the result of the query is a list, also if at the end is a unique  int value... so I have to convert the list into a number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `self.db.get` instead of `self.db.query`. Something like the following should work:

```
class NetworkStatusHandler(BaseHandler):
# Requires authentication 
@tornado.web.authenticated
def get(self, nid):

    # Retrieve the current user 
    usr = self.get_current_user()
    usr_id = usr['id']

    row = self.db.get("SELECT n.perm FROM nets_permissions as n \
                          WHERE n.network_id=%s AND n.user_id=%s", nid, int(usr_id))
    perm = row['n.perm']

    # Check whether the user has access to the network 
    perms = self.check_network_access(nid, perm)
    net = self.get_network(nid)
    # Render the networks page
    self.render("networkstatus.html", net=net)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have this error: File "./wsn.py", line 662, in get
    perm = int(rows[0]['perm'])
TypeError: 'long' object is unsubscriptable

My column perm in nets_permissions is an int(3), when the default length is 10... there's a possible problem with this? Why I have an error that talks of a long object???

Comment: Can you please confirm what library self.db comes from? I thought you mentioned tornado.database in which case you would be getting a list of objects.

Comment: I have a MySQL DB. Yes I've imported tornado.database

Comment: File "./wsn.py", line 662, in get
    perm = int(rows[0]['perm'])
KeyError: 0

I'd like to know what's the query returned...

Comment: Take that line out... I took it out of my answer.

Comment: Look, I'm more than happy to help answer questions but remote debugging is a PITA. Sprinkle some logging or prints around so you know what the database is returning, for example.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank you very much for your anyway helpful response. I'll try again! bye